# Filtering a FASTA file based on restriction-sequence with BioPython

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I have a fasta file. From that file, I need to get the only sequences containing `'CCNNNGG'` (where `'N'` represents random nucleotides) and put them in a new fasta file.

Example (it should output the first sequence):

> m121012_054644_42133_c100390582550000001523038311021245_s1_p0/7/3312_3597
>   CGCGGCATCGAATTAATACGACTCACTATAGGTTTTTTTATTG*********CCTACGG***********GTATTTTCAGTTAGATTCTTTCTTCTTAGAGGGTACAGAGAAAGGGAGAAAATAGCTACAGACATGGGAGTGAAAGGTAGGAAGAAGAGCGAAGCAGACATTATTCA
>
> m121012_054644_42133_c100390582550000001523038311021245_s1_p0/7/3708_4657
>   CAACGGTTTTGCCACAAGATCAGGAACATAAGTCACCAGACTCAATTCATCCCCATAAGACCTCGGACCTCTCAATCCTCGAATTAGGATGTTCTCGTACGGTCTATCAGTATATAAACCTGACATACTATAAAAAAGTATACCAT
>   TCTTATCATGTACAGTAGGGTACAGTAGG

(`*`s added for highlighting)

And my code:

```
 from Bio import SeqIO 


    my_sequences = []
    for record in SeqIO.parse(open("example.fa", "rU"), "fasta") :
         if "CCTACGG" in record.seq :                #Works fine with CCTACGG

            my_sequences.append(record)



    output_handle = open("my_seqs.fasta", "w")
    SeqIO.write(my_sequences, output_handle, "fasta")
    output_handle.close()
```

My problem is that I don't know how to write random nucleotides, instead of write `"CCTACGG"` after `if` I want to put `'CCNNNGG'`, where `N` represents random nucleotides (`'C'` or `'T'` or `'G'` or `'A'`).

Comment: So where is your code? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to do this, via Python's [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

pattern = 'CCNNNGG'
regex = re.compile(pattern.replace('N', '[ACGT]'))
for record in SeqIO.parse(...):
    if re.search(regex, record.seq) is not None:
        my_sequences.append(record)
```

This replaces every `'N'` in your pattern with `'[ACGT]'`, which will match any one of those four characters, then searches for that pattern in each `record.seq`.

Also, note that your examples aren't very good - the second one also matches that pattern (it contains `'CCCATGG'`) - see the [results](http://regex101.com/r/kT7aM0)!

Comment: Thank you, but It doesn't recognizes record.seq as a string. TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Try `str(record.seq)`, or `print` it to see exactly what it looks like.

Comment: This is likely to be problematic.  "re" does not perform overlapping matches, and restrictions sites (especially sites like this one, which has a short recognition sequence) may well overlap; so this approach might miss some sites.  One solution is to use the "regex" module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), which supports an "overlapped" flag.  Also, replacing the degenerate "N" with "ACGT" isn't necessary, and may miss sites in which low-quality sequencing or complex samples lead to "X" or "W" etc in the sequence.  Defining the regex as "CC...GG" is simpler and will catch these cases.